# How to pass a variable from one route to another in express-js

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, discord

I'm working with npm disco-oauth (to authenticate with discord) and when I authenticate in the app.js (main file) I save the userKey into a cookie (using cookie-parser) so I can get some user info as well as the guilds the user is in. But then, I want that user and a filtered guilds info to pass to a routes file (where I handle the dashboard routes) and I need to make some checks and those variables will be very handy to have whenever I want (I don't want to use queries and another method that use the URL to pass info because it doesn't look good).

The problem is that I tried to give cookieParser an object like this one:

```
app.get('/auth/discord', (req, res) => {
        if (req.cookies.userConfig.userKey) res.redirect('/guilds');
        else res.redirect(oauthClient.authCodeLink);
    })

    app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let userKey = await oauthClient.getAccess(req.query.code);
            let userConfig = {
               userKey: userKey,
               userID: " ",
               guilds: Guilds[]
            }
            await res.cookie('userConfig', userConfig);
            await res.redirect('/guilds');
        } catch (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        }
    });

    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        res.clearCookie("userConfig")
        res.redirect('/')
    })

    app.get('/guilds', async (req, res) => {
        if (!req.cookies.userConfig.userKey) res.redirect('/');
        else {
            try {
                let user = await oauthClient.getUser(req.cookies.userConfig.userKey);
                let GUILDS = await oauthClient.getGuilds(req.cookies.userConfig.userKey)



                var Guilds = []
                await GUILDS.forEach(async g => {
                    if (g.permissions.includes("MANAGE_GUILD")) {
                        await Guilds.push(g)
                    }
                })
                 //edit the cookie here to import the user and guilds values
                await res.render('guilds', {
                    user, //this is the user I want to pass
                    Guilds, //This is the guilds I want to pass
                    Servers: client.guilds.cache,
                    AdminIDs: keys.admin.discord_ids
                });

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.render('error', {
                    message: err.message,
                    error: err
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

The thing is the new cookie obj always returns "cannot read property userKey of undefined" but I don't understand why does it work when I pass only the **userKey** and when I try to put the full object (even if it only has userKey and empty user and guilds) it doesn't work. Does a cookie has any kind of limitation or am I doing it wrong? Please help

If that first part doesn't work I don't even want to try editing the cookie (see comment in code) and then grab that cookie and using it in other files and routes

**LAST WORKING VERSION**

```
app.get('/auth/discord', (req, res) => {
        if (req.cookies.userKey) res.redirect('/guilds');
        else res.redirect(oauthClient.authCodeLink);
    })

    app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let userKey = await oauthClient.getAccess(req.query.code);
            await res.cookie('userKey', userKey);
            await res.redirect('/guilds');
        } catch (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        }
    });

    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        res.clearCookie("userKey")
        res.redirect('/')
    })

    app.get('/guilds', async (req, res) => {
        if (!req.cookies.userKey) res.redirect('/');
        else {
            try {
                let user = await oauthClient.getUser(req.cookies.userKey);
                let GUILDS = await oauthClient.getGuilds(req.cookies.userKey)



                var Guilds = []
                await GUILDS.forEach(async g => {
                    if (g.permissions.includes("MANAGE_GUILD")) {
                        await Guilds.push(g)
                    }
                })

                await res.render('guilds', {
                    user,
                    Guilds,
                    Servers: client.guilds.cache,
                    AdminIDs: keys.admin.discord_ids
                });

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.render('error', {
                    message: err.message,
                    error: err
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are key value pairs separated by `;`. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

I'm not sure off the top of my head but I'll point you in the right direction with some troubleshooting strategies. `cookieParser` parses the cookie as a string from `req.headers.cookie`. I imagine it is some treatment that is happening in that library.

To troubleshoot, add stop points in your debugger or `console.log` the values of `req.cookies` and `req.headers` to see what's coming back.

It may turn out to be a bug or unaccounted for edge case in `cookieParser`.